# Unit test controller with IConfiguration using Moq and Mock setup returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, moq

New to Unit Testing web api.
I am writing a Unit test to Test a controller and I have to mock Iconfiguration. The appsettings,json has a section called "AppSettings", I'm trying to mock it.

Also, the mock.setup returns null value in the controller causing it to fail.

Here is my controller:

```
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ICarPairingTable PairingTable;
    private readonly ICarDealerSettingsTable DealerSettingsTable;
    static AppSettings appSettings = null;
    public CarController(IConfiguration configuration, ICarPairingTable carPairingTable, ICarDealerSettingsTable settingsTable)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        appSettings = configuration.Get<AppSettingsModel>().AppSettings;
        PairingTable = carPairingTable;
        DealerSettingsTable = settingsTable;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string id){
        string DealerId ="";
        
            
                DealerId = PairingTable.GetDealerId(id).Result;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DealerId))
                {
                    result = new ReturnResult
                    {
                        status = "Fail",
                        data = "ID is invalid"
                    };
                    return NotFound(result);
                }
           
           
            
            SettingsInfo info = DealerSettingsTable.GetSettingsInfo(DealerId).Result;
            if (info == null)
            {
                result = new ReturnResult
                {
                    status = "Fail",
                    data = "Not Found"
                };
                return NotFound(result);

            }
            result = new ReturnResult
            {
                status = "Success",
                data = info
            };
            return Ok(result);
    }
```

Here is my Unit Test:

```
   [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        var configurationSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();

        configurationSection.Setup(a => a.Value).Returns("testvalue");
        mockConfig.Setup(a => a.GetSection("AppSettings")).Returns(configurationSection.Object);

        var mock1 = new Mock<ICarPairingTable>();
       
        mock1.Setup(p => p.GetDealerId("456")).ReturnsAsync("123");
        var mock2 = new Mock<ICarDealerSettingsTable>();
        SettingsInfo mockSettings = new SettingsInfo()
        {
            DealerId = "123",
            
            Name="Dealer1"
        };
        mock2.Setup(p => p.GetSettingsInfo("123")).ReturnsAsync(()=>mockSettings);
        
        CarController controller = new CarController(mockConfig.Object,  mock1.Object, mock2.Object);
        var result = controller.Get("456");

        //Dont know what to assert

    }
```

Wrote unit test, but not sure if my approach is correct, Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a design issue wrapped in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Really should not be injecting `IConfiguration`. Based on how the configuration is using by the controller what you should have done was register the settings with the service collection in startup

*Startup.ConfigureServices*

```
//...

AppSettings appSettings = Configuration.Get<AppSettingsModel>().AppSettings;

services.AddSingleton(appSettings);

//...
```

and explicitly inject the settings into the controller

```
//...

private readonly AppSettings appSettings = null;
public CarController(AppSettings appSettings , ICarPairingTable carPairingTable, ICarDealerSettingsTable settingsTable) {
    this.appSettings = appSettings;
    PairingTable = carPairingTable;
    DealerSettingsTable = settingsTable;
}

//...
```

So now when unit testing the controller in isolation, you can initialize an instance of the desired class and provide when exercising the unit test.

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

You also appear to be mixing async-await and blocking calls like `.Result`.

I sugest you make the action async all the way

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string id){
    string DealerId = await PairingTable.GetDealerId(id);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DealerId)) {
        var result = new ReturnResult {
            status = "Fail",
            data = "ID is invalid"
        };
        return NotFound(result);
    }

    SettingsInfo info = await DealerSettingsTable.GetSettingsInfo(DealerId);
    if (info == null) {
        var result = new ReturnResult {
            status = "Fail",
            data = "Not Found"
        };
        return NotFound(result);
    }
    var result = new ReturnResult {
        status = "Success",
        data = info
    };
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

That way the unit test can finally be arranged correctly to verify the expected behavior

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Return_Ok_ReturnRsult() {
    //Arrange
    var id = "456";
    var dealerId = "123";
    SettingsInfo expected = new SettingsInfo() {
        DealerId = dealerId,
        Name="Dealer1"
    };

    var pairingMock = new Mock<ICarPairingTable>();
    pairingMock.Setup(p => p.GetDealerId(id)).ReturnsAsync(dealerId);

    var dealerSettingsMock = new Mock<ICarDealerSettingsTable>();
    dealerSettingsMock.Setup(p => p.GetSettingsInfo(dealerId)).ReturnsAsync(() => expected);

    CarController controller = new CarController(new AppSettings(),  pairingMock.Object, dealerSettingsMock.Object);

    //Act
    var actionResult = await controller.Get(id);
    var actual = actionResult as OkObjectResult;

    //Assert (using FluentAssertions)

    actual.Should().NotBeNull();

    actual.Value.Should().BeOfType<ReturnResult>();

    var actualResult = actual.Value as ReturnResult;

    actualResult.data.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);        
}
```